# Aptamers for DNA

Tags: dna

I know that aptamers have a high affinity for their target and are typically made of oligonucleotide s, but can I target DNA using aptamers? If not, what possible technologies can target DNA strands?

Comment: DNA can be targeted simply based on base complementarity. That's what antisense RNAs/oligonucleotides and CRISPR do.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused [aptamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptamer). It's actually a fairly common term in molecular biology. A single Google search would have answered your question.

Comment: @MattDMo Before writing that comment I've seen the wikipedia article; however i imagined the term is rare. I've deleted that suggestion-comment.